# Strawberry Perl: can't build Tcl module

Tags: windows, perl, tcl, strawberry-perl

I am having trouble building the Tkx module with Strawberry Perl on a Windows 10 platform. It is failing on the Tcl dependency. The errors are:

```
Tcl.o:Tcl.c:(.text+0x65): undefined reference to `__imp_Tcl_GetStringFromObj'
Tcl.o:Tcl.c:(.text+0x15e): undefined reference to `__imp_Tcl_ListObjGetElements'
Tcl.o:Tcl.c:(.text+0x1fb): undefined reference to `__imp_Tcl_GetStringFromObj'
Tcl.o:Tcl.c:(.text+0x29a): undefined reference to `__imp_Tcl_GetByteArrayFromObj'
Tcl.o:Tcl.c:(.text+0x4bf): undefined reference to `__imp_Tcl_NewStringObj'
Tcl.o:Tcl.c:(.text+0x538): undefined reference to `__imp_Tcl_NewDoubleObj'
Tcl.o:Tcl.c:(.text+0x58f): undefined reference to `__imp_Tcl_NewStringObj'
Tcl.o:Tcl.c:(.text+0x5d7): undefined reference to `__imp_Tcl_NewByteArrayObj'
Tcl.o:Tcl.c:(.text+0x621): undefined reference to `__imp_Tcl_NewListObj'
Tcl.o:Tcl.c:(.text+0x643): undefined reference to `__imp_Tcl_ListObjAppendElement'
Tcl.o:Tcl.c:(.text+0x6a1): undefined reference to `__imp_Tcl_NewObj'
Tcl.o:Tcl.c:(.text+0x6af): undefined reference to `__imp_Tcl_ListObjAppendElement'
Tcl.o:Tcl.c:(.text+0x6d1): undefined reference to `__imp_Tcl_NewIntObj'
Tcl.o:Tcl.c:(.text+0x786): undefined reference to `__imp_Tcl_NewByteArrayObj'
Tcl.o:Tcl.c:(.text+0x839): undefined reference to `__imp_Tcl_WrongNumArgs'
```

and many, many more similar errors. I searched, but I found nothing even close. The Strawberry Perl version is 5.26.4 and I did the recommended

```
cpan Tkx
```

I get the same errors when trying to build the Tcl module by itself with:

```
cpan Tcl
```

I have ActiveTcl installed, but Strawberry Perl doesn't seem to see it.

How do I get a working Tcl module for Strawberry Perl?

Comment: This is probably related to how ActiveTcl is built with Visual-C++ but Strawberry Perl is built with MinGW (if Strawberry Perl couldn't see your tclsh, you wouldn't even get this far).

Comment: This is this bug: https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=71535

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to get the build to work on Strawberry Perl 5.26. (The binutils package bundled with 5.24 seems to have a bug that makes it not recognize the `.lib` files from Tcl.)

The issue seems to be

```
Warning (mostly harmless): No library found for -ltcl86
```

in the vanilla build, because that library is definitely required. In my `C:\ActiveTcl\lib` there is indeed no `tcl86.lib`, but there is a `tcl86t.lib`.

So ...

1. Run `cpan`. This drops you in the cpan shell.
2. Run `look Tcl`. This downloads the Tcl module (if necessary) and drops you in the cmd shell in the build directory.
3. Edit `Makefile.PL` using your favorite editor.
4. Around line 183 there should be a line saying:

   ```
           $libpath .= " -ltcl$buildtype$tclver";
   ```

   Add another line after it:

   ```
           $libpath .= "t";
   ```
5. Save and exit your editor.
6. Run `perl Makefile.PL`. It should now be using `-ltcl86t`.
7. Type `exit` in the cmd shell to get back to the cpan shell.
8. Run `install Tcl`. This should go through successfully.
9. Type `exit` again to exit the cpan shell.